# После отправки запроса на сервер выполнить функцию без ожидания ответа от сервера

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как после отправки на сервер запроса через `jQuery.ajax()`, не дожидаясь ответа от сервера, выполнить свою функцию?

Т.е. запрос должен гарантированно отправиться, но не ожидать, пока скрипт выполнит действие и отправит ответ клиенту:

```
 $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: i,
        success: function(i)
        { //redirect();}
})
```

Comment: .

    $.ajax(...);
    anotherFunction();

не?

Comment: Нет, так не получится скрипт, интересует момент отправки в jQuery.ajax(). Т.е. что-то типа ajaxStart(), чтобы знать, что аjax сформировал, подготовил и отправил нужные заголовки на сервер.

Comment: @kosinus2012, не вызывайте функцию в success. Если её вызов должен быть как-то привязан к запросу, то можно вызвать в beforeSend:

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: ajaxurl,
      beforeSend: yourFunctionName,
      data: i,
      success: function(i){ 
        //redirect();
      }
    });

Comment: beforeSend, если память не подводит, выполняет до отправки запроса, в котором можно поменять заголовки "Use this to set custom headers, etc". Нужно именно после отправки на сервер, но без ожидания success статуса или error статуса.

Comment: @kosinus2012, насколько я понимаю формирование запросов - в этот момент запрос уже готов и послан в очередь. В крайнем случае можно c помощью таймаута задержать выполнение функции.

Comment: @Etki, я понимаю, что выполнить таймаут можно, но идея была в том, чтобы после отправки заголовков на сервер сразу осуществить релоад либо редирект страницы без ожидания ответа от сервера.   
Придется в исходниках ajaxStart() посмотреть, может, там что-то есть нужное. Спасибо, что помогли;-)

Comment: @kosinus2012, не знаю, но попробуйте еще [такой вариант][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ar56mq8k/2/

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо за ответ попробую + $.ajaxTransport просмотрю.

Comment: beforeSend работает

Answer (score 0):

$.ajax();

nextFunction();

Насколько понимаю этого вполне достаточно, сразуже после начала выполнения асинхронного кода (ajax) выполнится след блок кода - функция, не дожидаясь ответа ajax запроса.